Pytorch: Load multiple instances of a big model (need multiple GPUs to load 1 instance)
I have 8 GPUS and a big LLM which need multiple GPUs to load (e.g. 2 GPUs/instance)
How to load this with the current transformer/pytorch.
What I want is something equivalent to this where I can specify the GPUs that the model will be loaded to, and the device_map on these 2 GPUs are done automatically. I don't want to do the device_map manually.
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name_or_path, 
    devices=['cuda:0', 'cuda:1'], 
    device_map="auto"
)

Thanks
All of these should be done within 1 single python process.
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
